# Invalid shorthand property initializer in Chrome Console

Tags: javascript

I do not know why I got Uncaught SyntaxError for this code

```
const relationship2 = {
    name = 'zero',
    friends: ['nero', 'hero', 'xero'],
        logFriends() {
            this.friends.forEach(friend => {
                console.log(this.name, frined);
            });
        },
};
```

Comment: replace `name = 'zero'` to `name : zero`

Comment: Oh Thank you my mistake...

Answer (score 3):

Object needs `key/value` pair which are seprated by `:`not `=`

change this

```
name = 'zero',
```

to this

```
name : 'zero',
```